# How to rearrange query results into new columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

My query currently gives these results

```
+-------+---------+------------+-------+
| Amount| Location| Description|   User|
+-------+---------+------------+-------+
|  100  |      A  |       Fire |   Jim |
+-------+---------+------------+-------+
|   75  |      B  |      Water |   Joe |
+-------+---------+------------+-------+
|   75  |      B  |       Fire |   Joe |
+-------+---------+------------+-------+
|   58  |      A  |       Fire |   Sam |
+-------+---------+------------+-------+
|   72  |      D  |      Earth |   Jim |
+-------+---------+------------+-------+
|  128  |      C  |        Air |   Bob |
+-------+---------+------------+-------+
|  128  |      A  |        Air |   Sam |
+-------+---------+------------+-------+
```

I want to take these results and rearrange and sum them. Grouping by Locations, and User.

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|    |  Jim|  Joe|  Sam|  Bob|  Total|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   A|  100|    0|  186|    0|    286|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   B|    0|  150|    0|    0|    150|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   C|    0|    0|    0|  128|    128|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   D|   72|    0|    0|    0|     72|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|   E|    0|    0|    0|    0|      0|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: For your information this is called a [tag:pivot]. Doing it directly in MySQL is a notorious pain in the neck.

Comment: Thank you. I was having trouble trying to describe what it was I was even trying to do. This should at least help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1):

As o.Jnes told it is a pivot problem, that can be solved.

This way

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `Amount` INTEGER,
>   `Location` VARCHAR(1),
>   `Description` VARCHAR(5),
>   `User` VARCHAR(3)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`Amount`, `Location`, `Description`, `User`)
> VALUES
>   ('100', 'A', 'Fire', 'Jim'),
>   ('75', 'B', 'Water', 'Joe'),
>   ('75', 'B', 'Fire', 'Joe'),
>   ('58', 'A', 'Fire', 'Sam'),
>   ('72', 'D', 'Earth', 'Jim'),
>   ('128', 'C', 'Air', 'Bob'),
>   ('128', 'A', 'Air', 'Sam');
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT 
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>     CONCAT(
>       'SUM(CASE `User` WHEN "',
>      `User`,
>       '" THEN `Amount` ELSE 0 END) AS `',
>       `User`, '`'      
>     )
>     ORDER BY `Location`
>   ) 
>   INTO @sql
> FROM table1 as p
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = CONCAT('select `Location`, ',@sql,', SUM(`Amount`) from table1
> group by `Location`
> ORDER BY `Location`');
>
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> Location | Sam | Jim | Joe | Bob | SUM(`Amount`)
> :------- | --: | --: | --: | --: | ------------:
> A        | 186 | 100 |   0 |   0 |           286
> B        |   0 |   0 | 150 |   0 |           150
> C        |   0 |   0 |   0 | 128 |           128
> D        |   0 |  72 |   0 |   0 |            72
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1918fd115b100e5186688232f2f95d6)*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with this for the moment. I need to refine it to use whatever names are in the column, but this works for now.

```
select 
    column8 as 'Charge Code',
    sum(case when column9 = 'name1' then column6 else 0 end) as name1,
    sum(case when column9 = 'name2' then column6 else 0 end) as name2,
    sum(case when column9 = 'name3' then column6 else 0 end) as name3,
    sum(column6) as 'Total'
```